# Changing JS fetch call to PHP and AJAX call not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fetch, bootstrap-modal

I originally had a JavaScript function to fetch wikipedia articles for the selected country. I originally found the code on JS Fiddle and it worked perfectly, however I've since been advised that my course requires all API calls to be made via PHP and AJAX.

```
// ----- Function responsible for grabbing country name & code to populate wikipedia modal -----//
//adapted from JSFiddle
function getWikiSearch(countryName) {
    let ids = "";
    let links = [];
    let results = [];

    fetch("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&origin=*&srsearch=" + countryName)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(result => {
            results = result.query.search;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (results[i + 1] != null) {
                    ids += results[i].pageid + "|";
                } else {
                    ids += results[i].pageid;
                }
            }
        })
        .then(a => {
            fetch("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&inprop=url&origin=*&format=json&pageids=" + ids)
                .then(idresult => {
                    return idresult.json();
                })
                .then(idresult => {
                    for (i in idresult.query.pages) {
                        links.push(idresult.query.pages[i].fullurl);
                    }
                })
                .then(g => {
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
                    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        if (i < 3) {
                            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br><br><a href='" + links[i] + "'target='_blank'>" + results[i].title + "</a><br>" + results[i].snippet + "... Click title to read full article.";
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
}
```

For the reason above, I have tried to adapt the code:
**PHP file for the 1st fetch statement (2nd is in exactly the same format, just appropriate URL)**

```
<?php

// Display errors is set to on and should be removed for production
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Timing script execution
    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&origin=*&srsearch=' . $_REQUEST['countryName'];
// Curl object is initiated
    $ch = curl_init();
    
//Curl_setopt() takes three parameters(Curl instance to use, setting you want to change, value you want to use for that setting)    

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result, true);   
    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['result'] = $decode;

    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

Then the AJAX call like so:
**AJAX call**

```
function getWikiSearch() {
    let countryName = $('#innerSelect option:selected').text()
    if (countryName == 'United Kingdom') {
    countryName = 'UK'}

    let ids = "";
    let links = [];
    let results = [];

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "assets/php/getWiki.php",
        data: {
               countryName: countryName
                },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result)
        
            results = result.query.search;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (results[i + 1] != null) {
                    ids += results[i].pageid + "|";
                } else {
                    ids += results[i].pageid;
                }
            }
            console.log(ids)
                $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "assets/php/getWikiID.php",
                data: {
                       id: ids
                        },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result)
                    for (i in idresult.query.pages) {
                    links.push(idresult.query.pages[i].fullurl);
                    
                    document.getElementById("wikiSearch").innerHTML = "";
                            for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                if (i < 3) {
                                    document.getElementById("wikiSearch").innerHTML += "<br><br><a href='" + links[i] + "'target='_blank'>" + results[i].title + "</a><br>" + results[i].snippet + "... Click title to read full article.";

                            }}
                }}})
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(jqXHR)
                            console.log(textStatus)
                            console.log(errorThrown)
                                }
                    })
        }
```

and the **HTML**

```
      <!-- Wikipedia Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="wikiModal">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <!-- Modal Header -->
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Wikipedia Information</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
               </div>
               <!-- Modal body -->
               <div class="modal-body">
                  <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Search Wikipedia">
                  <button id="wikiBtn" onclick="wikiSearch(document.querySelector('#input').value)">
                  Search
                  </button>
                  <hr>
                  <div id="output"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Whilst the console is displaying the appropriate JSON results in the console, nothing is appearing in the Modal?

[image]

With the original fetch statement code (first code stated) my Modal looked like this
[image]

I'm not sure how to fix the code so it displays as expected

Comment: It sounds like your next step is to use your browser's debugging tools to specifically observe the responses from the server and step through the response handling code in the JavaScript.  When you do this, which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?

Comment: What does getWikiID.php look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have these lines:

```
for (i in idresult.query.pages) {
links.push(idresult.query.pages[i].fullurl);
```

But `idresult` doesn't exist.  I think that's a typo and it should just be

```
for (i in result.query.pages) {
links.push(result.query.pages[i].fullurl);
```

---

In the first AJAX request you have

```
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result)
        
            results = result.query.search;
```

However the response from getWiki.php actually looks like:

```
{
   "status":{
      "code":"200",
      "name":"ok",
      "description":"success",
      "returnedIn":"310 ms"
   },
   "result":{
      "query":{
         "search":[
            {
               ...
            },
      }
   }
}
```

So you'd have to refer to `result.result.query.search`.  I'm going to guess it maybe the same problem with the 2nd AJAX request.

---

In your HTML you have `<div id="output"></div>`.  But in the JS you refer to `document.getElementById("wikiSearch")`.  Change the name of one or the other to be consistent.

---

Here's the full JS code I was able to get working

```
function getWikiSearch() {
    let countryName = $('#innerSelect option:selected').text()
    if (countryName == 'United Kingdom') {
        countryName = 'UK'}

    let ids = "";
    let links = [];
    let results = [];

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "getWiki.php",
        data: {
            countryName: countryName
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(response) {
            results = response.result.query.search;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (results[i + 1] != null) {
                    ids += results[i].pageid + "|";
                } else {
                    ids += results[i].pageid;
                }
            }

            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "getWikiId.php",
                data: {
                    id: ids
                },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(response) {
                    for (i in response.result.query.pages) {
                        links.push(response.result.query.pages[i].fullurl);

                        document.getElementById("wikiSearch").innerHTML = "";
                        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            if (i < 3) {
                                document.getElementById("wikiSearch").innerHTML += "<br><br><a href='" + links[i] + "'target='_blank'>" + results[i].title + "</a><br>" + results[i].snippet + "... Click title to read full article.";
                            }}
                    }}})
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR)
            console.log(textStatus)
            console.log(errorThrown)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: oh thanks! It's still not acting as expected though :/ not doing anything if I search and when I open the modal it should already have 3 articles displayed for the selected country